# PHP: Escaping RegEx-reserved characters - anyone know what's wrong with this?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I'm trying to escape regex-reserved characters with a backslash (don't ask -- suffice it to say I'm NOT trying to parse HTML :) ) And I'm getting something odd.

```
$regex_chars = array('[' , '\\' , '^', '$' , '.' , '|' , 
    '?' , '*' , '+' , '(' , ')');  
$regex_chars_escaped = array('\[ ' , '\\\\ ' , '\^ ', '\& ' , 
    '\. ' , '\| ' , '\? ' , '\* ' , '\+ ' , '\( ' , '\)'); 
$escaped_string = str_replace($regex_chars,$regex_chars_escaped,
     implode("",$regex_chars));
echo implode('&nbsp;',$regex_chars) . "<br />";
echo $escaped_string;
```

Spaces are for clarity. This is the output

```
[ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )
\\ [ \\ \^ \& \. \| \? \* \+ \( \)
```

So all is good, except for the first part. Where does the  "\\" come from and why isn't it "\[" ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not simply use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)?

Comment: probably because I'm a damn moron. Thank you!

Comment: +1 on your comment not because you're a damn moron, but because you're a damn funny moron.

Comment: The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's just because of the order you're putting the chars in the array. Try this:

```
$regex_chars = array('\\' , '[' , '^', '$' , '.' , '|' , 
        '?' , '*' , '+' , '(' , ')');  
$regex_chars_escaped = array( '\\\\ ' ,'\[ ', '\^ ', '\& ' , 
        '\. ' , '\| ' , '\? ' , '\* ' , '\+ ' , '\( ' , '\)');
```

And you should get the expected output. Check the **'potential gotchas'** section in the [str_replace function spec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: I ended up using preg_quote, but this is useful to know, thank you.